# How to I make the image switch back to the original image src after Iv'e pressed the button once

Tags: javascript, html, src

```
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='hagthrowingball.gif'">Throw Fire ball</button>

<img id="myImage" src="foresthag.gif" style="width:100px">


</body>
</html>
```

I need the image src onclick to show the image hagthrowingball.gif, but then go back to foresthag.gif without pressing the button again.

Comment: This is going about doing things in The Old Ways. Inline `onclick` handlers are discouraged, learn to use [.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead. A better way to swap images is to have an element, say a `div` with a class and a CSS _style_ that places the image for that class - switching images then is just a matter of adding and removing (toggling) classes on the element. Read about an elements [clasList](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) where you can add, remove, and toggle classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should solve your problem by automaticly setting back old src after some time;

```
<button onclick="replaceFunc();">Throw Fire ball</button>

<img id="myImage" src="foresthag.gif" style="width:100px">

<script>
  function replaceFunc (){
      const el = document.getElementById("myImage");
      const oldSrc = el.src;
      el.src = 'hagthrowingball.gif';
      setTimeout(()=>el.src=oldSrc, 1000);
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```